# Jquery live() binding doesn't work on some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do this:

```
JQ('body').delegate('a','click',function() {alert('test');})
```

All links shows alert after click. 
But one link not shows.
How do you think, why?
What can cause this?

Comment: What does this one link look like?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Does the link that's not working have any other event handlers attached to it?

Comment: First Note that `live`  and `delegate` have been deprecated, use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead (technically `delegate` has just been superseded by `.on`). That said do you have some sample markup?

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS it looks like other links.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist yes, there's some otheres handlers on it.

Comment: @AlexeiMalashkevich Ok, can we see the HTML and those other handlers?

Comment: @Jack. I don't think that it will be useful. I write some kind of plug-in to forum on lithium engine (http://lithosphere.lithium.com/). I think, that this link already has .live() handlers. Can they kill my?

Comment: @AlexeiMalashkevich I was just pointing that out in case you weren't aware, as for an earlier handler messing up yours, it is indeed [possible](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to assume something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/uAgS4/ is happenning.

```
$('body').delegate('a', 'click', function(event) {
    alert('working');
    event.preventDefault();
});

$('.disabled').click(function () {
    return false;
});
```

​Basically, you are capturing the event elsewhere and preventing propagation. [jQuery.Event stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) is effectively the same as returning `false`.

Comment: So do you think that some of other functions can return false and it can stop handling?

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon what exactly are you trying to do.. Was the link in the page in the first place when you assigned the event. Or was it added later into your DOM..
Also posting your code and markup should help..

Comment: I assign event in $.ready(). I think, markup doesen't help you. But if you really need it...